# $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the equation $(a-2)x^2-(5-a)x-5=0$. Find $a$ if $|\alpha - \beta|=2 \sqrt {6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the equation $(a-2)x^2-(5-a)x-5=0$. Find $a$ if $|\alpha - \beta|=2 \sqrt {6}$

I cannot understand how to proceed with this problem. Please show me the logic behind this problem.

Comment: Please ask your question in the body, not just in the title. [Your question must be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144).

Comment: Solve quadratic as stated to get 2 roots as functions of a.  Then use the condition to get an equation for a.

Comment: Hint: You should know the values of $S=\alpha+\beta$ and $P=\alpha\beta$ without computing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (that is, *without solving the quadratics*). Now, can you express $(\alpha-\beta)^2$ in terms of $S$ and $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Vieta formulas,

$$\alpha+\beta=\frac{5-a}{a-2}$$ and

$$\alpha\beta=-\frac5{a-2}.$$

Then

$$|\alpha-\beta|=\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4\alpha\beta}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+10a-15}}{|a-2|}=2\sqrt 6$$

which you can solve for $a$ (two solutions).

Comment: If you worked out the problem, the solution is $a = 3$ or $a=\frac{37}{23}$

Comment: Crossed TheSimplifire.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The condition is equivalent to $(\alpha-\beta)^2=24$, and 
$$(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta,$$
a symmetric function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by Vieta's formulas, we have $$\alpha+\beta=-\frac{-(5-a)}{a-2}=-\frac{a-5}{a-2}=-1+\frac3{a-2}$$ and $$\alpha\beta=-\frac5{a-2}$$ so $$(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta.$$ Hence all you need to do is solve $$\sqrt{(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta}=2\sqrt6$$ for $a$.

Comment: You inverted the formulas !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for correcting!